# Simplest way to secure debian server on LAN

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, firewall, gateway

I currently have a basic debian server setup and connected to my LAN.

Am I right in thinking that if I remove the gateway from the network configuration then the box will be unable to communicate with the internet but still be accessible to machines on my LAN?

I am trying to work out the simplest way of securing the box whilst I play with the IPTables configuration

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, by not having a default gateway will not allow the machine to communicate with external hosts, but still allow communication within the same subnet.

What is it you want to accomplish? If you want to make the server unreachable on the LAN, just pull the plug on it. You can use iptables if you need more fine-grained policies, like allowing only certain ports or certain IP addresses.

Comment: I want to make the server only accessible on the LAN.  It's going to be my file storage and I only want people on my local network to be able to access it

Comment: Not having a default gateway will to that, but that will also stop updates. You'll want iptables rules that allow only the internal network. Note that if you have a NAT router, outside users will be unable to reach your server anyway (this is not a security feature but a by-effect of using NAT).

Answer (score -1):

Unplug its ethernet cable or do `route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 127.0.0.1 lo`

Comment: I am not trying to disconnect it from the LAN, just make it unable to access the internet

Comment: The null route will work then.